# Selecting the row of UITableView does not matter?

Tags: ios, uitableview, row

I have a "UITableView", I am trying to handle selected row and use its data accordingly,

I have written necessary code to take the selected row, unfortunately it seems it does not work

If i select nothing,

```
NSIndexPath *path = [tableViewDoctorName indexPathForSelectedRow];
int rowSelected = path.row;
```

rowSelected's value is 0;

But, when i select the row it is again 0.

I have only one row in a table, i am not sure does it matter?

How can i accurately determine the selected row in a "UITableView"?

Comment: start by checking that your indexPath is not nil. If it's nil there is no cell selected. But if you use `int x = path.row` and path is nil, x will be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Set the UITableView delegate and implement this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
           int rowSelected = indexPath.row;
 }
```

Comment: check my answer you will get it.

Answer (score 1):

`indexPath.row` start with **0** for first row, And you have only one row then it return always **0**;

But if you want to get data of selected Row then you delegate method of `UITableView`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  
  // here you can get directly indexPath.row so you can get required data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course how many rows you have in your tableView matters : if you only have 1, then its indexpath is (0 ,0) and this is the only one that can be (selected) in this case.

The selected row generally is highlighted (in blue) so you might want to store it in another property of your tableView delegate, if you don't want this blue selection to stay on-screen.

Typically, in your `UITableViewDelegate` :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // deselect the row, to avoid the 'blue' selection to stay on-screen
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    // save your own copy of 'last' selected indexPath
    self.mySavedIndexPath = indexPath;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

In outside the function,
use this to get selected row,

```
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: _selectedIndexPath.row inSection:0];
int rowSelected = indexPath.row;
```